# Secondary domain in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have two sites, site 01 and site 02:

site = 01 has content 
site = 02 has the video

When the user clicks the button "watch" the video is not loaded on the same page, the visitor goes to the site domain 02.

Google Analytics records this visit but he tells it like bounce rate and then it does not count the visit time visitor to see the video, since for some reason the site Analytics not recognizes 02 as being my property and also an extension of site 01.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you done any configuration to your Analytics property? For example, set up any type of cross domain tracking? Are theese websites on the same top-level domain and uses different subdomains, or are they two totally diferent TLDs?